# How to add responsiveness to Tablets through Positioned and padding widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to use MediaQuery within LayoutBuilder and for all Positioned - Material buttons I need to add different logic for tablets ,small phone and big phone and I want to add if and else statement for these through mediaQuery

this if statement is displaying a error when I put it under positioned.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var deviceData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    double _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      return OrientationBuilder(builder: (context, orientation) {
      Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
double width = size.width > size.height ? size.height : size.width;      
        if (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 600) {
          isLargeScreen = true;
        } else {
          isLargeScreen = false;
        }
        SizeConfig().init(constraints, orientation);


  Positioned (
                                // height: context.heightPct(.99),
                                // width: context.widthPct(.99),
                                // Container(
                                // alignment: Alignment(,-.3),
                                //  child:   FractionallySizedBox(
                                // widthFactor: 30,                      
                               if (isLargeScreen){
                                width: 213 * SizeConfig.imageSizeMultiplier,
                                height: 92 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                                  }else{
                                height: 92 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                                width: 213 * SizeConfig.imageSizeMultiplier,

 child: Opacity(
                                  opacity: 0.9,
                                  // left: width*0.5,
                                  // top: 900,
                                  // top: 100,
                                  child: _visible
                                      ? MaterialButton(
                                          // minWidth:screenSize.width*0.1,
                                          // 0.1 = 10% of the screen , 0.5 = 50% of the screen
                                          // ios sizes usually are 620...
                                          // height: screenSize.height*0.1,
                                          onPressed: () => changeTextArabic1(),
                                          onLongPress: () =>
                                              changeTextEnglish1(),
                                          // shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(60.0)
                                          // child: Text(labels[i]),
                                          // ),
                                          child: Ink(
                                            child: Text(surah0),
                                            //  disabledTextColor: Colors.transparent,
//                       color: Colors.cyan[300],
//                       // color: Colors.purple[300],
//                       highlightColor: Colors.blue,
//                       // shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(60.0)
//                       // ),
//                       textColor: Colors.white,
                                            // color: Colors.cyan[400],

                                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(21.0),
                                            // padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                            //     left: 28,
                                            //     top: 25,
                                            //     right: 28,
                                            //     bottom: 25),
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              gradient: LinearGradient(
                                                colors: [
// all together looks COOL royal Blue:
                                                  Colors.red,
                                                  Colors.blue,
                                                  // Color(0xff374ABE),
                                                  // Color(0xff64B6FF),
                                                  // Color(0xff0E0077),
                                                  // Color(0xff1B00EE)
                                                ],
                                                // begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                                // end: Alignment.centerRight,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          // color: Colors.blue[300],
                                          // highlightColor: Colors.blue,
                                          // ),
                                          textColor: Colors.white,
                                        )
                                      : Container(),
                                  // ),

                                  //  ):Container()
                                ),
      
                                  }),
```

Comment: use `isLargeScreen? someThing : someThingElse`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
isLargeScreen 
? Positioned()
: Positioned()
```

or:

```
Positioned(
  height: isLargeScreen ? something : something,
  width: isLargeScreen ? something : something
)
```

Comment: Thanks I tried but I am getting error: // Iphone x
                                  width: 213 * SizeConfig.imageSizeMultiplier,
                                  height: 92 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                                  // Ipad AIr 
                                  height: isLargeScreen? 92 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                                  width: isLargeScreen? 213 * SizeConfig.imageSizeMultiplier,

Comment: Hi , My question was how can i add this for two different phone sizes .. withing the same positioned widget ... ?

Comment: So you can use my my second piece of code and just replace "something" with the screen size of your choice

Comment: Hi sorry  I tried this, and I am getting the top number to move for both iPad and Iphone, but the bottom number is doing nothing:      height: isLargeScreen? 92 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier
// Iphone above
: 213 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                                // IPad above
                                width: isLargeScreen
                                    ? 130 * SizeConfig.imageSizeMultiplier
                                    // Iphone above
                                    : 230 * SizeConfig.imageSizeMultiplier,

Comment: I even tried:    Positioned(
                         height: isLargeScreen ? 95 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier: isSmallScreen?  95 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                         width: isLargeScreen ? 125 * SizeConfig.imageSizeMultiplier: isSmallScreen? 125 * SizeConfig.imageSizeMultiplier no luck.... please help

Comment: I don't understand what top number and bottom number is? Is it your height and width?
Also, if there are any errors, you should also write it out, for me to see what is wrong, or to see if my answer to your question is inapplicable